# Nested Routes not rendering with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to group some of my routes together with React Router v4 to clean up some of my components.  For now I just want to have my non logged in routes group together and my admin routes grouped together but the following doens't work.

### main.js

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Public} />
        <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

### public.js

```
const Public = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Greeting} />
      <Route path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
      <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Public;
```

The Greeting component shows at "localhost:3000/", but the SignupPage component does not show at "localhost:3000/signup" and the Login component doesn't show at "localhost:3000/signup". Looking at the React Dev Tools these two routes return Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very obvious. for your route in main.js, you have specified the Route path of `Public` component with exact `exact path='/'` and then in the Public component you are matching for the other `Routes`. So if the route path is `/signup`, at first the path is not exact so `Public` component is not rendered and hence no subRoutes will.

Change your route configuration to the following

**main.js**

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Public} />
        <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Main
```

**public.js**

```
const Public = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Greeting} />
      <Route path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
      <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Also when you are specifying the nested routes these should be relative to the parent Route, for instance if the parent route is `/home` and then in the child Route you wish to write `/dashboard` . It should be written like

```
<Route path="/home/dashboard" component={Dashboard}
```

or even better

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That does make sense.  I guess I was trying to combine old React Router nesting with React Router v4 methods.  Thanks for the help. It is obvious now that I look at it.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to have helped